# ¿Cómo puedo guardar campos específicos de un CSV?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Tengo un fichero de excel con diferentes filas y columnas.

Tengo que recorrer ese fichero fila por fila, y de cada fila guardar ciertos campos en variables para luego compararlos.

El tema es, hago por ejemplo:

```
x = `echo $LINEA | cut -f15 -d, nombre.txt`
```

(LINEA es la linea actual del fichero), y lo que hace es guardarme toda la columna 15 entera hasta el final del fichero.

En cambio yo solo quiero el campo de la columna de esa fila, no toda la columna del fichero.

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer combinación de dos filtros: `head` y `tail` . El primero te coje las N primeras filas, y el segundo las últimas N filas. Combinando esos filtros puedes obtener fila en concreto

Comment: Pero yo la fila en la que estoy ya es la que quiero. Es decir hago un For LINEA in "cat ... texto" y me coloca en la primera linia del excel. Lo que quiero entonces es guardar un campo de esa linia, nose si me explico...

Answer (score 2):

EL problema que te sucede es que haces el echo, se lo colocas al cut y te devuelve todas las columnas 15 del fichero y tu error esta en el cut, que le estas diciendo que corte el campo 15 del fichero nombres.txt separado por la ,
Así pues el echo anterior no tiene ningún efecto sobre el cut. Tienes que eliminar el fichero y el cut actuará sobre lo que le has pasado con el echo $LINEA

```
echo $LINEA | cut -f15 -d,
```

Mírate el comando awk, lo mismo te da mas opciones y mas facilidad de lo que crees para tratar operaciones con el contenido del fichero. Un ejemplo que te hace lo mismo

```
awk -F, '{ print($15) }' nombres.txt
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias probare así ;)

Comment: Buena respuesta. Si el OP quiere por ejemplo la línea 10, podrías decir `awk -F, 'NR==10 {print $15}' fichero`, pues "NR" contiene el valor del registro que se está leyendo en cada momento (registro=línea en la mayoría de los casos).

Comment: deberías comprobarlo con un if, awk lo que hace es lee el fichero nombres.txt y le pasa el script a cada línea que lea.

Comment: @Spidvmp ¿me contestabas a mí? No entiendo tu comentario

Comment: si, el awk se trata todo el fichero, si solo quieres una linea o le pones un if os sacas solo la linea que quieres con un head -10 nombre.txt | tail -1 | awk -F, '{....}'